# Is MonoDevelop's editor slow for you?

Tags: iphone, macos, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using the evaluation version of MonoTouch and MonoDevelop to check out writing iPhone app in C#.  However, MonoDevelop's editor is very slow for me.  I mean really really slow.  I have to type and wait for text to be rendered.

Do you experience the same?  Any insights on what can be the causes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

If you're using MonoDevelop 2.8.2 (the one used in Unity 4, for example) it may just be the Git plugin on MonoDevelop.

Go to the "Add-in Manager..." menu item and disable the Version Control plugins (or just "Git support").

Comment: Was using git and this worked for me, MonoDevelop is about 10x faster and actually responsive.  Thanks.

Comment: THANKYOU! I've been suffering back performance for almost a year now until I stumbled upon this.

Comment: This ["duplicate" and/or related answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/356129/monodevelop-performance-in-unity-4.html) sucks! *I want to use Git*!! :(

Comment: @Cawas: It's a pity we can't link Unity answers and StackOverflow. I still used git, but not directly in the Monodevelop IDE. It's a matter of preference, but even on XCode, that does have decent git support, I still use git externally.

Comment: I meant mono's git. its diff and log features are great, and I miss them. I think you got it I just meant it's disappointing the add-in is so buggy with Unity's MonoDevelop. And it's not the first time this happens.

Answer (score 2):

We have heard about this bug on some MacBooks but we are unable to reproduce.

Would you mind trying this trick, some people have reported that this fixes the problem for them (we recently added this to our http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Troubleshoot page):

Sometimes the MonoDevelop source editor becomes extremely slow, appearing to hang for several seconds between typing characters.

This issue is very rare and extremely hard to reproduce - it usually cannot be reproduced on the same machine after restarting MonoDevelop. For this reason we would appreciate it if you could perform several debugging steps before restarting MonoDevelop, and send the results to us.

1. Try closing the editor tab, and re-opening it. Does it take a little bit of editing or moving the caret around until the slowdown happens again?
2. Disable "Beam Sync" using the "Quartz Debug" developer tool (which you can find using Spotlight), and check whether the source editor performance is restored to normal.
3. Try repeating step (1) with Beam Sync still disabled.
4. If the editor hangs for more than a few seconds, try to run "killall -QUIT monodevelop" in a terminal while it is hung. It may be difficult to time the kill command to happen while the editor is hung, but it's essential to do so, because the command forces Mono to write stack traces of all threads to the MD log, which we can use to discover what state the threads are in while the MD is hung.

Please attach the MD log, ~/.config/MonoDevelop/log (in future versions of MD it is ~/Library/Logs/MonoDevelop/MonoDevelop.log).

Comment: Miguel, is this a current issue still? I have MonoDevelop slowing to a crawl quite regularly (and variably, sometimes it's ok) on my Core2Duo 2.0 plastic MacBook. Latest stable MT and MD as of today.

Comment: I have the same issue with a twist: I have a 3.46GHz Core I7 990x Extreme and it takes 4 seconds or more to move the cursor in a new project. Win7 64 bit running Linux Mint in virtualbox. That might make it easier for you to reproduce the issue. I'll see if I can get you my stack traces FWIW.